# Dropdown in jade / Node js

Tags: node.js

I have used this code to make a dropdown... but it's not display to my jade page. What's Wrong with the code?

```
 select(name='tipekamar')
  option(value='VVIP') VVIP
  option(value='VIP') VIP
  option(value='KELAS 1') KELAS 1
  option(value='KELAS 2') KELAS 2
  option(value='KELAS 3') KELAS 3
```

Comment: a space before `select`?

Comment: oke it show but this change as a submit function... any script for dropdown?